# Rails 3 object.belongs_to_id to object.belongs_to.name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails 3 project where the index.html.erb currently includes `<td><%= chapter.university_id %></td>` whereas what I want it to show should be `<td><%= chapter.university.name %></td>` however, this is currently throwing the exception **undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass** Interestingly, chapter.foo.name is working to access information from another model to which "chapter" belongs.  Can anyone help standardize this?

***EDIT:***

In an attempt to replicate this error in another way, I changed `<td><%= chapter.university.name %></td>` to `<td><%= chapter.university.id %></td>`, hoping that I could convince rails to give me university_id from the universities table, rather than the chapters table.  Still no luck, but gave the error **Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id** rather than **undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass** which I had previously been receiving.

I have also checked and re-checked the 'has_many'/'belongs_to' relationships between `chapter` and `university` as well as `chapter` and `foo` and found the working and non-working relationships to be identical.  I have even gone so far as to switch the order in which those relationships are declared within the models, to no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to have been a problem with the way fixtures were loading into the database.  Dependencies were not being observed, and so random data was being placed into the university_id column on the universities table. Cleaning out the bad data and replacing it with manually entered data solved the problem.